# Can I get namespace of a click event?

Tags: jquery

Say I have this code:

```
function bindIt(ns) {

    $(document).on('click.' + ns, '[my-custom-attribute]', function (e) {
        // How can I say ... if (namespace == 'ns3') { .... };
    });

};

bindIt('ns1');
bindIt('ns2');
bindIt('ns3');
bindIt('ns4');
```

The above code will cause the click event to run 4 times, but how do I get the specific namespace (eg. compare to ns3 in the sample above)?

Comment: This question has strong hints of [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Try explaining the problem you're trying to *solve* rather than exactly how you're trying to *achieve* it.

Comment: With the code you've provided, the namespace part is available in the method as `baseID`.

Comment: Sry for not being clear - I tried to rewrite my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve it using :

```
e.handleObj.namespace
```

But depending expected behaviour, sounds like there is better way to do what you are looking for, `namespace` shouldn't carry data.

Comment: Super - perfect!!! Thanks. Well I'm writing an internal pluing (for my company) and there's LOTS of HTML that will be reused for each instances - so using namespace I'm sure to callback the correct instance.